# how to correctly set multiple ranges to be called by the row header in a function?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range, named-ranges

I am making a simple team calendar that shows travel, PTO, training etc in excel.  The events are color coded by shading the corresponding cell on a row with your name as the header.

i am using the function GetColorCount to count the number of cells colored a certain color to create a summary table.

The formula works but since i have multiple rows selected in the cell formula, the formula will not auto update the count when a color change is made. D39 is the cell with the desired matching color.  there are multiple rows called out because the calendar is set up by weeks of the month to make it easier to view versus all 365 days layed out in a single row.

```
Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range)
Dim CountColorValue As Integer
Dim TotalCount As Integer
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
  If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
    TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
  End If
Next rCell
GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function
```

what i would like to do is define the range of this function as a parameter by searching the name that is listed in the 1st cell column of the summary table(A45:F49) against the row headers in column A from A1:A33 in the data area A3:DD33.

in the hopes that this would cause the function to auto update anytime the cell format is changed.

```
Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range)
Dim CountColorValue As Integer
Dim TotalCount As Integer
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
  If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
    TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
  End If
Next rCell
GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function
```

sheet cell formula

```
=GetColorCount(($3:$3,$9:$9,$15:$15,$21:$21,$27:$27),D39)
```

Comment: Changes in cell formatting don't trigger any recalculation.

Comment: "...in the hopes that this would cause the function to auto update anytime the cell format is changed"   
My question is how and when the cell format is changed?

Comment: And one more question, does cell D39 have a value or are you only using it for its color?

Comment: cell D39 is only a colored cell.  the cell format is changed manually by clicking the cell to select it and then choosing the fill color.